# Left shift gives me strange results

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("left shift 1 = %d\n", 1 << 1);
    printf("left shift 2 = %d\n", 1 << 2);
    printf("left shift 3 = %d\n", 1 << 3);
    printf("left shift 4 = %d\n", 1 << 4);
    printf("left shift 5 = %d\n", 1 << 5);
    printf("left shift 6 = %d\n", 1 << 6);
    printf("left shift 7 = %d\n", 1 << 7);

    return 0;
}
```

and I got the output like this:

```
left shift 1 = 2
left shift 2 = 4
left shift 3 = 8
left shift 4 = 16
left shift 5 = 32
left shift 6 = 64
left shift 7 = 128
```

It seem correct for number 1 and 2, but what happened to other numbers from 3 to 7?

Comment: Isn't each one twice the previous, as expected?

Comment: "what happened to other numbers from 3 to 7?" - nothing out of ordinary, they're correct. How are they "strange", in your opinion?

Comment: Those are correct numbers. If you were expecting something different, you don't understand what left-shift does.

Comment: Each left shift increases the value to the next *Power of Two*.

Comment: Are you mixing up operands? In all cases it's 1 left shifted by operand on the right of << operator, not the other way around.

Comment: oh , I just found out that 1 << 3 , means left shift 1 to 3 bits. But I just mistakend that 1 << 3 means left shift 3 by 1 bit,  sorry about that . So it is all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left shift operation `n << 1` in fact multiplies the left operand by 2. And the result of your program shows this.

Let's assume that you have an object named `n` of the type char:

```
0000 0001
```

then  n << 1 gives:

```
0000 0010
```

that in the decimal notation is 2:

n << 2 gives

```
0000 0100
```

that in the decimal notation is 4:

n << 3 gives

```
0000 1000
```

that is the decimal notation is 8.

And so on.

Comment: "in fact multiplies the left operand by 2" it does that *by definition*. It's not a mere useful fact.

Comment: @Ayxan You are wrong. Processors shift instructions are not the same as multiplication instructions. They are different instructions.

Comment: Look up C18 §6.5.7/4. Definition of `E1 << E2` is `E1 × 2 ^ E2`.

Comment: @Ayxan In the C11 Standard there is written "4 The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2E2..." The same is written in the C 20.

Comment: Yes, the value of the result is `E1 × 2 ^ E2` even if you have a 1's complement representation, or even a decimal machine

Comment: Just a minor clarification: the left shift being the same as doubling is only guaranteed for *unsigned* types, of which `int` is not one.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing strange about that at all. For an unsigned integer (also *usually* for a signed integer where you don't encroach on the sign bit, but this is not mandated by the standard), a left shift is basically a doubling of the value.

And that's exactly what you're seeing:

```
1 << 0 = 0000 0001 =   1
1 << 1 = 0000 0010 =   2
1 << 2 = 0000 0100 =   4
1 << 3 = 0000 1000 =   8
1 << 4 = 0001 0000 =  16
1 << 5 = 0010 0000 =  32
1 << 6 = 0100 0000 =  64
1 << 7 = 1000 0000 = 128
```

Answer (score 0):

What you experience is the correct behavior of the shifting operator.

Let's start from illustrating the decimal representation of a byte:

```
ByteDecValue = 
    bit0 * 2^0 +
    bit1 * 2^1 +
    bit2 * 2^2 +
    bit3 * 2^3 +
    bit4 * 2^4 +
    bit5 * 2^5 +
    bit6 * 2^6 +
    bit7 * 2^7
```

So, for example, the decimal value corresponding to the byte `00010010b` is `2^4 + 2^1 = 18 dec`.

An interesting particular scenario occurs when **only one byte** is 1. Deriving the formula from the one above we can say

```
ByteDecValue_bit_N = 2^N

2^0 = 1 << 0 = 0000 0001
2^1 = 1 << 1 = 0000 0010
2^2 = 1 << 2 = 0000 0100
2^3 = 1 << 3 = 0000 1000
2^4 = 1 << 4 = 0001 0000
2^5 = 1 << 5 = 0010 0000
2^6 = 1 << 6 = 0100 0000
2^7 = 1 << 7 = 1000 0000
```

That's exactly what you experience: by shifting 1 to the left N times you get a single 1 in position N, so the power 2^N.

**Note:** your test would have been complete by printing also the value of `1 << 0`. In that case you would have got `2^0 = 1`. No shift at all means keeping the original value.